# C++ library for peer to peer communication over internet for desktop application

Tags: open-source, library, c++, c, communication

I am looking for a C++ library for peer to peer communication over internet for a desktop application.

The library should contain the code for client machine and Signalling/Handshake server. It should have APIs for video call, video conference, audio call, audio conference, file transfer, messaging and screen sharing. It should work on Windows, Linux and macOS.

I have found [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/tree/master/examples), but it is too complex to customize. Can you suggest any better C++ library than this?